# Aplicar estilo css a toda la fila de una tabla

Tags: css

Tengo una tabla con varias filas y cada fila está dividida en tres columnas, la cantidad es lo de menos.

En la columna de la mitad tengo un texto, y en las columnas de cada lado de esa misma fila unos íconos de Font Awesome.

Necesito que el estilo font-weight: bold; se aplique a toda la fila, incluyendo los íconos y no sólo al texto.

Cómo puedo lograr esto?

Añado el código, también lo pueden ver en [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/JheyMejia/pen/LgZZvY?editors=1000)

```css
td {
padding: 10px 0;
border: 2px solid #000;
text-align: center;
cell-spacing: none;
            }

tr:hover {
background-color: #ddd;
font-weight: bold;
        }

.far:hover {
font-weight: bold;
  
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <table style="width:100%">
    
 <tr>
   
 <td width="10%"><i class="far fa-file-word"></i></td>
   
 <td width="80%">Lorem Ipsum</td>
   
<td width="10%"><a href="#"><i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-down"></i></a></td>

</tr>

<tr>
   
 <td width="10%"><i class="far fa-file-pdf"></i></td>
   
 <td width="80%">Lorem Ipsum</td>
   
<td width="10%"><a href="#"><i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-down"></i></a></td>

</tr>
    
<tr>
   
 <td width="10%"><i class="far fa-file-excel"></i></td>
   
 <td width="80%">Lorem Ipsum</td>
   
<td width="10%"><a href="#"><i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-down"></i></a></td>

</tr>    

</table>
  
</body>
```

Comment: Cuando necesitas colocar el font-weight: bold? cuando este hover? o siempre debe de tener ese font-weight: bold?

Comment: Cuando esté en hover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo jugué con el selector `tr:hover` para lo que quieres:

```css
td {
padding: 10px 0;
border: 2px solid #000;
text-align: center;
cell-spacing: none;
}

tr:hover td,
tr:hover td .far{
 background-color: #ddd;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <table style="width:100%">
    
 <tr>
   
 <td width="10%"><i class="far fa-file-word"></i></td>
   
 <td width="80%">Lorem Ipsum</td>
   
<td width="10%"><a href="#"><i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-down"></i></a></td>

</tr>

<tr>
   
 <td width="10%"><i class="far fa-file-pdf"></i></td>
   
 <td width="80%">Lorem Ipsum</td>
   
<td width="10%"><a href="#"><i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-down"></i></a></td>

</tr>
    
<tr>
   
 <td width="10%"><i class="far fa-file-excel"></i></td>
   
 <td width="80%">Lorem Ipsum</td>
   
<td width="10%"><a href="#"><i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-down"></i></a></td>

</tr>    

</table>
  
</body>
```

como verás agregue `tr:hover td` y `tr:hover td .fa`, con eso quiero decir que cuando el mouse este arriba del la fila al `td` y al elemento que tenga la clase `.far` le coloque el `font-weight: bold;`.

Espero que sea lo que estas buscando.

Comment: Exacto, marcaré tu respuesta como correcta por el plus de la descripción de cómo lo lograste. Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Este código te puede funcionar, es simple y rápido, me comentas que tal te funciona.

```
td {
padding: 10px 0;
border: 2px solid #000;
text-align: center;
cell-spacing: none;
}

tr:hover {
background-color: #ddd;
font-weight: bold;
}

tr:hover .far {
background-color: #ddd;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

[**REVISA EL CÓDIGO AQUÍ (CODEPEN)**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZqOpZY)